# Modify the HTTP response content after PHP has finished generating a response

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I have a question for modify `responseText` of `xmlhttprequest`.

`index.html` sends a `xmlhttprequest(req)` to `b.php`, (`index.html` and `b.php` both place in Tests folder)

`b.php` echos  binary (`video/mp4`) data.

```
$url="/stream/stream.m4s";
$data=file_get_contents($url);

header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

echo $data;
```

I print `req.responseText` in `index.html`,
I get `responseText="/Tests/b.php?url=/stream/stream.m4s"`.

Jow to modify `responseText` content after `b.php` has finished generating a response. (don't modify `index.html` or `b.php`)

**Example**: response is written as `"/abc/Tests/b.php?url=/stream/stream.m4s"`

Please give me some suggestions, Thanks.

i simplify my question: how to append/modify response content after php has finished generating a response. b.php echo the string such as "abc". and append/modify the response string to "123abc" via apache(or others) before sending to browser. browser(req.responseText) will get "123abc" stirg. How to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please edit your post and add in some snippet of your code that makes the request to b.php. You should also look at `fpassthru()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php

Comment: i simplify my question: how to append/modify response content after php has finished generating a response. b.php echo the string such as "abc". and append/modify the response string to "123abc" via apache(or others) before sending to browser. browser(req.responseText) will get "123abc" stirg. How to do that? Thanks!

Comment: This makes less sense now. We need further code examples. What does `index.html` use?

Answer (score -1):

Would advise another method:

```
<?php

// open the file in a binary mode
$url="./stream/stream.m4s";
$fp = fopen($url, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($url));

// dump the file and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;

?>
```

Also when you make your AJAX call, you will want to wait for `success` or `done` before operating, so that you know you have the content passed back and rendered in the DOM. Since Video files are larger, you might start processing other code before the data is passed back to your AJAX request.

Need more help? Post more of your code.

Comment: i simplify my question: how to append/modify response content after php has finished generating a response. b.php echo the string such as "abc". and append/modify the response string to "123abc" via apache(or others) before sending to browser. browser(req.responseText) will get "123abc" stirg. How to do that? Thanks!